# Can I use boolean parameters in LogitModelFit?

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics

For example, to use `1` as `True` and `0` as `False`:

```
LogitModelFit[{{300, 0, 0}, {400, 0, 0}, {450, 1, 0}, {460, 1, 1}}, {x, y}, {x, y}]
```

where `y` is boolean parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the documentation about the option `NominalVariables`

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NominalVariables.html

> NominalVariables is an option for machine learning functions such as LinearModelFit or
>   Classify that specifies which variables should be treated as having
>   discrete values specified by names.

So

```
LogitModelFit[{{300, 0, 0}, {400, 0, 0}, {450, 1, 0}, {460, 1, 1}}, {x, y}, {x, y},
  NominalVariables -> y ]
```

shoud do the job.

[image]

You ae not required to use 0 and 1 for your binary variables, you can use more meaningful symbol and strings, like True/False or "Male"/"Female", and so on.